# Pipe CURL result to BC

Tags: bash, shell, curl, sed, bc

I have a CURL command

```
echo "{cur_format}" | curl -w @- -s -o /dev/null https://example.com
```

Let's say the above command outputs a string of "**I waited 1 day**".

How can I convert "I waited 1 day" to "I waited 24 hours" (i.e. pipe "1 * 24" to the bc command")?

Thank you.

Comment: You would have to extract the 1, multiply, and then shove it back into the string

Comment: A better solution might be to pipe to Awk, but. what exactly the script should look like depends on how general you need it to be. `awk '{$3 *= 24; $4 = "hours"; print }'` does what you ask.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you! "awk" solves my problem.

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. Feel free to post your latest edit as an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by using "awk" command. For example,

```
echo "{cur_format}" | curl -w @- -s -o /dev/null https://example.com | awk -F'[:\|]' '{print $1 ":" (($2*24)) "|" $3 "|" $4;}'
```

Note that -F'[:\|]' is a list of any delimiters you need.